# IPC using Named Pipes in C++ and Python program hangs

Tags: python, c++, ipc, named-pipes

I'm practicing IPC by using named pipes on Unix and trying to write a string in FIFO file using python & reversing it through C++ program. But the program in Python gets hanged & returns no result.

Python Code For writing into file:

```
import os
path= "/home/myProgram"
os.mkfifo(path)
fifo=open(path,'w')
string=input("Enter String to be reversed:\t ")
fifo.write(string)
fifo.close()
```

The program hangs and doesn't ask for any input here.
I get following error when I break out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "writer.py", line 4, in <module>
    fifo=open(path,'w')
KeyboardInterrupt
```

C++ code for reading from file:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024
using namespace std;

char* strrev(char *str){
    int i = strlen(str)-1,j=0;

    char ch;
    while(i>j)
    {
        ch = str[i];
        str[i]= str[j];
        str[j] = ch;
        i--;
        j++;
    }
    return str;

}


int main()
{
    int fd;
    char *myfifo = "/home/myProgram";
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
    cout<<"Received:"<< buf<<endl;
    cout<<"The reversed string is \n"<<strrev(buf)<<endl;
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Since, the writer program fails to execute, unable to test the reader code and hence can't mention the result here.

Please help.

Comment: You got it backwards. The reader should be the one creating the pipe and waiting for writers to open it.

Comment: When did `os.mkfifo` become supported on Windows?  My Python documentation says it is Unix only.

Comment: Yes, I'm using it on UNIX only.. :)

Comment: Do you run the reader program at the same time as the writer program?

Comment: No, since nothing gets written at first, how could one read a blank file? so, using this logic, I just execute writer program first. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't use python but an output pipe can block waiting for the other end to start reading.

Comment: @Khushbu> I thought my first comment up there did just that ;). To elaborate: a fifo is **not** a file, it is a communication channel. It cannot be sent to if there is nothing listening at the other end.

Comment: If I run reader file first, it is not able to find the newly created file myProgram.fifo and returns with error 'File Not Found'

Comment: Yes, don't run the reader first. Run the writer first. But try running the reader while the writer is still running.

Comment: Usually you don't have permission to open a pipe in the `/home/` directory. Did you mean `$HOME`? Because that would be `/home/usrname/myProgram.fifo` (substitute `username` with your *actual* username).

Comment: Using your code (after fixing the location of the pipe)  it works for me when I run the reader at the same time the writer is running (obviously run the writer first then the reader).

Comment: My actual path is  /Users/username/home/myProgram.fifo

Comment: Does the `/home` directory exist on your machine?  Do you have read/write privs to that location?

Comment: Do the actual programs contain `/Users/username/home/myProgram.fifo` as the actual path for the FIFO pipe location (with "username" substituted for the actual)?

Comment: yes, the actual path in program is exactly same as pipe location, with read and write privileges for my username.

Comment: Yes, simultaneously running the two files worked flawlessly! But i get the following error while running the reader.cpp file:                                               Warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings]
    char *myfifo = "/Users/username/Desktop/myProgram";

Comment: Try `char const* myfifo = "/Users/username/Desktop/myProgram";` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The python code blocks in `open()`.  It is waiting for a reader.

One might normally switch to nonblocking and use `os.open()`.  With a FIFO, you will get an error, ENXIO.  This basically equates to, no reader present.

So, the "owner" of the FIFO should be the reader.  This rule might simply be a matter of style.  I am not aware of specific reasons for this constraint.

Here is some python code that demonstrates interleaving multiple readers and writers.

```
    import os
    r1 = os.open('myfifo', os.OS_RDONLY | os.OS_NONBLOCK)
    r2 = os.open('myfifo', os.OS_RDONLY | os.OS_NONBLOCK)
    w1 = os.open('myfifo', os.OS_WRONLY | os.OS_NONBLOCK)
    w2 = os.open('myfifo', os.OS_WRONLY | os.OS_NONBLOCK)
    os.write(w1, b'hello')
    msg = os.read(r1, 100)
    print(msg.decode())
    os.write(w2, b'hello')
    msg = os.read(r2, 100)
```